# split string to string builder with removing all words match the pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string of words separated by `([ \\t{}():;.,،\"\n])`. How can I split that string to a `StringBuilder` while removing any word that matches the pattern `@"\d|\s|/|-"` and also removing all words with less than 2 character of length. Finally, I want to store it back into string.

```
Regex r = new Regex("([ \\t{}():;.,،\"\n])");

    String[] tokens = r.Split(sb.ToString());
    List<string> filter = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
    {
        ........................
        {
            .....................
        }


    }

    ................

    return builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Try to make a RegEx instance out of the second regex and use that same instance for all calls to IsMatch in the loop. Maybe this will speed it up.

Comment: is it possible to do it with fast Linq code ?

Comment: Can you provide an example input string, and the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this. It's not much different from your solution, except I'm using LINQ and avoiding the StringBuidler at all. Would it be acceptable for you?

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string value = "one or:another{3}";
        Regex exclude = new Regex(@"\d|\s|/|-", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        string final = string.Join(" ",
            (from s in Regex.Split(value, "([ \\t{}():;.,،\"\n])")
                where s.Length > 2 && !exclude.IsMatch(s)
                select s.Replace("ه‌","ه")).ToArray());

        // to get the List<string> instead:
        List<string> l = (from s in Regex.Split(value, "([ \\t{}():;.,،\"\n])")
            where s.Length > 2 && !exclude.IsMatch(s)
            select s.Replace("ه‌","ه")).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: but i want to store back into string.

Comment: Well, test it on your real input. I think it's just avoiding some unnecessary steps (the StringBuilder bit, the List<string>) but I wouldn't think it will be blazing fast. If you are aiming at speed, then maybe something lower level would be better?

Comment: @Jone: here you are getting a string at the end. YOu don't need to store back because you have a string directly.

Comment: i want to do just one replace on each word when it stores back, where i have to put this replace.?

Comment: @Paolo.if u are avoiding the string builder, so what does StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); do?

Comment: how can I return the output as a List<string>?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks pretty good to me.  Regex processing does take a good long time.  Perhaps try creating `@"\d\s|/|-"` as `Regex m = new Regex(`@"\d\s|/|-");` at the top to avoid reparsing it on each lap.

Comment: Ideally this would be done as a set-based operation rather than a loop to increase speed and efficiency -- O(1) rather than O(n).  Perhaps try reformatting as LINQ or move this into a stored procedure -- both set-based environments.